# Нарисовать дугу в QGraphicsItem

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, gui

Есть класс `class Edge : public QGraphicsItem`, в котором реализовано рисование стрелок от одной вершины (`Node`) до другой (скрин ниже).
Теперь необходимо добавить возможность рисовать стрелку на себя(а именно дугу).
И тут у меня проблемы. Не могу корректно нарисовать дугу и ее корректную область выделения.
Ниже код где я либо рисую стрелку либо дугу. Полный проект на [github](https://github.com/fryn3/elasticnodes.git).

```
Edge::Edge(Node *sourceNode, Node *destNode)
    : id(_idStatic++), arrowSize(15)
{
    setFlag(QGraphicsItem::ItemIsSelectable);
    source = sourceNode;
    dest = destNode;
    source->addEdge(this);
    if(source != dest)
        dest->addEdge(this);
    adjust();
}

QPolygonF Edge::nPolygonMath() const {
    QPolygonF nPolygon;
    if (source != dest) {
        QLineF line = QLineF(sourcePoint.x(), sourcePoint.y(), destPoint.x(), destPoint.y());
        qreal radAngle = line.angle() * M_PI / 180;
        qreal selectionOffset = 3;
        qreal dx = selectionOffset * sin(radAngle);
        qreal dy = selectionOffset * cos(radAngle);
        QPointF offset1 = QPointF(dx, dy);
        QPointF offset2 = QPointF(-dx, -dy);
        nPolygon << line.p1() + offset1
                 << line.p1() + offset2
                 << line.p2() + offset2
                 << line.p2() + offset1;
    } else {
        nPolygon << mapFromItem(source, -Node::Radius, -Node::Radius)
                 << mapFromItem(source, Node::Radius, -Node::Radius)
                 << mapFromItem(source, Node::Radius, Node::Radius)
                 << mapFromItem(source, -Node::Radius, Node::Radius);
    }
    return nPolygon;
}

QRectF Edge::boundingRect() const
{
    if (!source || !dest)
        return QRectF();

    return nPolygonMath().boundingRect();

}

QPainterPath Edge::shape() const{
    QPainterPath ret;
    ret.addPolygon(nPolygonMath());
    return ret;
}

void Edge::paint(QPainter *painter, const QStyleOptionGraphicsItem *option, QWidget *)
{
    if (!source || !dest)
        return;

    painter->setPen(QPen((option->state & QStyle::State_Selected ? Qt::cyan: Qt::black), 2, Qt::SolidLine, Qt::RoundCap, Qt::RoundJoin));
    if (source != dest) {
        QLineF line(sourcePoint, destPoint);
        if (qFuzzyCompare(line.length(), qreal(0.)))
            return;

        // Draw the line itself
        painter->drawLine(line);

        // Draw the arrows
        double angle = std::atan2(-line.dy(), line.dx());

        QPointF destArrowP1 = destPoint + QPointF(sin(angle - M_PI / 1.8) * qMin(arrowSize, line.length()),
                                                  cos(angle - M_PI / 1.8) * qMin(arrowSize, line.length()));
        QPointF destArrowP2 = destPoint + QPointF(sin(angle - M_PI + M_PI / 1.8) * qMin(arrowSize, line.length()),
                                                  cos(angle - M_PI + M_PI / 1.8) * qMin(arrowSize, line.length()));

        painter->setBrush((option->state & QStyle::State_Selected ? Qt::cyan: Qt::black));
        painter->drawPolygon(QPolygonF() << line.p2() << destArrowP1 << destArrowP2);
    } else {
        painter->drawArc(mapFromItem(source, Node::Radius, 0).x(),
                         mapFromItem(source, Node::Radius, 0).y(),
                         2 * Node::Radius, 2 * Node::Radius, 16 * -90, 16 * 180);

    }
}
```

[image: Сейчас стрелка выделена голубым]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для этого начал отталкиваться от центра вершины. Центр дуги размести в (центрВершины.х + радиусВерш, центрВершины.у - радиусВерш).
Перегрузка `shape()` для выделения нарисовал круг с радиусом на 2 пикселя больше, что бы вмещала толщину ручки(`QPen`).
Перегрузка `boundingRect()` основывается на shape().
В перегрузке `paint(...)` нарисовал дугу от -70 градусов до 270. -70 что бы не вылезала из линий "стрелочек".
Проект все так же на гитхабе. Может кому поможет)

```
void Edge::adjust()
{
    if (!source || !dest)
        return;

    if(source != dest) {
        QLineF line(mapFromItem(source, 0, 0), mapFromItem(dest, 0, 0));
        qreal length = line.length();

        prepareGeometryChange();
        if (length > qreal(2 * Node::Radius)) {
            QPointF edgeOffset((line.dx() * Node::Radius) / length, (line.dy() * Node::Radius) / length);
            sourcePoint = line.p1() + edgeOffset;
            destPoint = line.p2() - edgeOffset;
            // Нахождение точки для текста
            QLineF line1(sourcePoint, destPoint), line2;
            if (line1.angle() >= 0 && line1.angle() <= 180) {
                line1.setLength(line1.length() - 30);
                line2.setPoints(line1.p2(), line1.p1());
            } else {
                QLineF line11(destPoint, sourcePoint);
                line11.setLength(30);
                line2.setPoints(line11.p2(), line11.p1());
            }
            QLineF line3 = line2.normalVector();
            line3.setLength(12);
            textPoint = line3.p2();
        } else {
            sourcePoint = destPoint = line.p1();
        }

    } else {
        textPoint = QPointF(boundingRect().center().x() - Node::Radius / 2, boundingRect().center().y());
        prepareGeometryChange();
        sourcePoint = mapFromItem(source, 0, -Node::Radius);
        destPoint = mapFromItem(source, Node::Radius, 0);
    }
}
// Для столкновений и выделения
QPainterPath Edge::shape() const{
    QPainterPath path;
    if (source != dest) {
        QLineF line = QLineF(sourcePoint.x(), sourcePoint.y(), destPoint.x(), destPoint.y());
        qreal radAngle = line.angle() * M_PI / 180;
        qreal selectionOffset = 3;
        qreal dx = selectionOffset * sin(radAngle);
        qreal dy = selectionOffset * cos(radAngle);
        QPointF offset1 = QPointF(dx, dy);
        path.moveTo(line.p1() + offset1);
        path.lineTo(line.p1() - offset1);
        path.lineTo(line.p2() - offset1);
        path.lineTo(line.p2() + offset1);
    } else {
        path.addEllipse(source->pos() + QPointF(Node::Radius, -Node::Radius),
                        Node::Radius + 2, Node::Radius + 2);
    }
    return path;
}

// Для отрисовки
QRectF Edge::boundingRect() const
{
    if (!source || !dest)
        return QRectF();
    if (source != dest) {
        QPolygonF pText;
        qreal x = textPoint.x();
        qreal y = textPoint.y();
        pText << QPointF(x, y)
              << QPointF(x, y - 110)
              << QPointF(x + 70, y - 110)
              << QPointF(x + 70, y + 10)
              << QPointF(x, y + 10);
        return shape().boundingRect().united(pText.boundingRect());
    }
    return shape().boundingRect();
}
void Edge::paint(QPainter *painter, const QStyleOptionGraphicsItem *option, QWidget *)
{
    if (!source || !dest)
        return;
    double angle;
    QPointF peak, destArrowP1, destArrowP2;
    painter->setPen(QPen((option->state & QStyle::State_Selected ? Qt::cyan: Qt::black), 2, Qt::SolidLine, Qt::RoundCap, Qt::RoundJoin));
    if (source != dest) {
        QLineF line(sourcePoint, destPoint);
        if (qFuzzyCompare(line.length(), qreal(0.)))
            return;

        // Draw the line itself
        painter->drawLine(line);
        // Draw the arrows
        angle = std::atan2(-line.dy(), line.dx());

        destArrowP1 = destPoint + QPointF(sin(angle - M_PI / 1.8) * qMin(arrowSize, line.length()),
                                                  cos(angle - M_PI / 1.8) * qMin(arrowSize, line.length()));
        destArrowP2 = destPoint + QPointF(sin(angle - M_PI + M_PI / 1.8) * qMin(arrowSize, line.length()),
                                                  cos(angle - M_PI + M_PI / 1.8) * qMin(arrowSize, line.length()));
        peak = line.p2();
    } else {
        painter->drawArc(source->pos().x(),
                         source->pos().y() - 2 * Node::Radius,
                         2 * Node::Radius,
                         2 * Node::Radius,
                         16 * -70, 16 * 270);
        angle = 1.07*M_PI;
        destArrowP1 = destPoint + QPointF(sin(angle - M_PI / 1.8) * arrowSize,
                                                 cos(angle - M_PI / 1.8) * arrowSize);
        destArrowP2 = destPoint + QPointF(sin(angle - M_PI + M_PI / 1.8)* arrowSize,
                                                 cos(angle - M_PI + M_PI / 1.8) * arrowSize);
        painter->setBrush((option->state & QStyle::State_Selected ? Qt::cyan: Qt::black));
        peak = destPoint;

    }
    painter->setBrush((option->state & QStyle::State_Selected ? Qt::cyan: Qt::black));
    painter->drawPolygon(QPolygonF() << peak << destArrowP1 << destArrowP2);

    painter->drawText(textPoint, "x2 y2");

}
```

[image: Результат!]

Comment: https://github.com/fryn3/elasticnodes -- исходники какие то